# What to do after creating a new app and change the bundle id?

Tags: ios

I want to re-release my app under a slightly different name and stop supporting the old one.

I created a new app. Change bundle id. When I want to archive I got

```
The provisioning profile specified in your build settings (“May Provisioning Profile for Distribution”) has an AppID of “com.appname” which does not match your bundle identifier “appname”.  Xcode can resolve this issue by downloading a new provisioning profile from the Member Center.
```

What should I do?

There is nothing in itunes connect that talks about provisioning profile, etc.

Comment: You get provisioning profiles from - as the message explains - the [Member Center](https://developer.apple.com/membercenter), not from iTunes Connect. Click on "Manage your certificates, App IDs, devices, and provisioning profiles" from the main page.

Answer (score 0):

> There is nothing in itunes connect that talks about provisioning profile

This has nothing to do with iTunes Connect. It has to do with building / archiving. Your provisioning profile for distribution of this app was tied to your bundle id. You changed the app's bundle id. Therefore you killed your provisioning profile for distribution of this app. So just make a new one tied to the new the new bundle id.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a distribution provisioning profile in the [Member Center](https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action), and then refresh your profiles in Xcode once you've created it. The [Create Store Provisioning Profiles](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/SubmittingYourApp/SubmittingYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH9-SW1) section of the App Distribution Guide explains how, you must have done this when you released your original app.

Answer (score 0):

As you have changed you bundleId you have to recreate your provisingprofile with new register app.